# Why does scalatest matcher `should not include` not compile with FlatSpec, but work with FunSuite

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

I am using scala 2.9.3 and scalatest_2.9.3-1.9.2. I am having trouble using the matchers to assert that a string does NOT contain a substring:

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers._

class Learning extends FlatSpec {
  behavior of "..."
  it should "..." in {
    val msg = "Upload successful"
    msg should include ("successful")  // compiles
    msg should not include ("error")   // does not compile
  }
}
```

Oddly, when I extend `org.scalatest.FunSuite`, the compilation error disappears. What's going on?

The compilation error reported is:

```
[ant:scalac] Learn.scala: error: value include is not a member of org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers.ResultOfNotWordForLengthWrapper[java.lang.String]
[ant:scalac]     serialized should not include ("error")
[ant:scalac]                           ^
[ant:scalac] one error found
```